# How to fix this Bad operand

Tags: java, jframe

I Need To convert years of days and this error stops me.
help please.. need to pass it now.
error: bad operand types for binary operator '*'
error: result = screen * 365;
                       ^

```
 import java.awt.*;
 import javax.swing.*;
 import java.awt.event.*;

 public class DaysOfYears extends JFrame implements ActionListener 
{
   JTextField screen = new JTextField(30);
   JButton conBtn = new JButton("Convert");
   JLabel jb = new JLabel ("");

  private double result;


 public DaysOfYears(){
 super("Convert Your Years in Days");
 setSize(400, 200);
 setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
 setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

  add(screen);      
    add(conBtn);
    add(jb);
    conBtn.addActionListener(this);
  }
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){

    result = screen * 365;
    jb.setText(""+result);
  }


      public static void main (String[] args) {
        DaysOfYears days = new DaysOfYears();
     days.show(true);
   }
  }
```

Comment: `screen` is a `JTextField`, how would you suggest Java multiple a `JTextField` by 365?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JTextField holds its contents as String. You will need to convert it to integer unless of course you are supplying a string representation of a double data type within the JTextField.

Try something like:

result = Integer.valueOf(screen.getText()) * 365;

Comment: Thanks, This Works for Me.. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you wanted to parse the text value of your `JTextField` and **then** perform your *multiplication*. Something like,

```
result = Integer.parseInt(screen.getText()) * 365;
```

Note that leap years have 366 days.

Answer (score -1):

Here screen is a object of `JTextField`so multiply operation will not perform on the `object` of `JTextField` type you can grab the values of this object **convert** it into any `Number` type then try to multiplying. It will solve your problem .

Try this......

```
        result = Integer.parseInt(screen.getText()) * 365;
           // this will perform multiply actually. Thnak you
```

Comment: Please tell me if i add .`toString()`  method what will be problem?? can u explain whoever u r?